# This beta version has expired

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, xamarin.android

I am developing monodroid application and everything seems to be working fine [I was able to run the android project before] till one fine day and suddenly I got this error message while running the android application from VS2010.
[image]

Than I downloaded the monodroid installer from here http://go-mono.com/monodroid-download/
and when I tried to run it I am getting the below error[image]

I am confused. How to resolve this error?

Comment: This is not a vendor-support forum. Contact Monodroid's support for this type of question.

Comment: So I guess we shouldn't be answering any questions about Visual Studio or Eclipse then, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonoDroid isn't free, you need to license it.  Sounds like the license expired.

Comment: +1 I was so excited that I didn't notice that monodroid is not a free version. I am very disappointed now :-(

Comment: Why?  If it lets you use your existing skills and code base for your application, seems like a small price to pay to get your app on Android.